# Sequent reading from socket on Windows fails (haskell sockets)

Tags: windows, sockets, haskell, tcp

I wrote a simple TCP-client for some device, which consumes and produces 8-byte packets (the code of send-command-receive-result function is below).

When I run it on linux, it works perfectly, being part of the loop (send-recv-send-recv-...), but on windows it receives only first msg from device (send-recv-send-send-...). The packets are still going - I could clearly see them with Wireshark - but something under my client just ignores them (or truncates to zero?). It doesn't even print `"Data was read!"` - looks like the reading stucks and gets killed by `timeout` function.

Before that, I used the sockets directly; changing to `HandleStream` yelded no difference at all. Wrapping `main` in `withSocketsDo` did nothing, too.

```
transmit :: Int -> HandleStream ByteString -> ByteString -> IO [Bytestring]
transmit delay sock packet = do
    let input = timeout delay $ sock `readBlock` 8 <* putStrLn "\nData was read!"

    sock `writeBlock` pack

    strings <- whileJust input

    return [str | Right str <- strings]

whileJust action = do
    result <- action

    case result of 
        Just a  -> (:) <$> return a <*> whileJust action
        Nothing -> return []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using the Network.TCP for now.